# Why the following python is not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following python coding is written to generate the triangle numbers between 1 to 55. But the coding is not working why ?

```
num = 1
sum = 0
while (num <= 10)
    sum = sum + num
    num = num + 1
print (sum, end=' ')
```

Comment: What does not working mean - are you getting an error or not desired results? Note: Indentation is important in Python, the `print()` needs to be indented into the `while` loop (and you need to end the `while` statement with a `:`)

Comment: Assuming you are actually using Python 3.x, not Python 2.x, the `:` is the only issue. `print` as a function is not supported by default in Python 2.x without a library import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing colon :

```
num = 1
sum = 0
while (num <= 10):
    sum = sum + num
    num = num + 1
print (sum, end=' ')
```

or

```
num = 1
sum = 0
while (num <= 10):
    sum = sum + num
    num = num + 1
    print (sum, end=' ')
```

Output

```
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

For 2.7

```
num = 1
sum = 0
while (num <= 10):
    sum = sum + num
    num = num + 1
    print sum,
```

Comment: Its run perfectly Output 55

Comment: Ah! thank you. But how to print in python 2.7 with space?

Comment: 2.7 print  sum ,

Comment: No, it is showing as error in equal(=)

Comment: num = 1
sum = 0
while (num <= 10):
    sum = sum + num
    num = num + 1
    print sum,

Comment: This will show only 55. But I want 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55

Comment: nop it will show  1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55  do place print sum , inside the while loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150670/discussion-between-s-sakthybaalan-and-hariom-singh).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is an error that is not followed by a while statement, followed by a `()` wrap and end of print that are not supported by default in Python 2.x.

**The Corrected Code is:**

```
num = 1
sum = 0
while (num <= 10):
    sum = sum + num
    num = num + 1

print sum
```

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` introduces the `print()` in Py2.7, and the equivalent `print` statement would end with a `,`

Comment: thx! @AChampion but using library